# Are moderators etc. focusing on trying to get better questions, when they should be focusing on getting better answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, questions

Are moderators etc. focusing on trying to get better questions, when they should be focusing on getting better answers?

Seems to me that'd be a misallocation of resources.

I believe virmaior was the 1st moderator on this site, and they seem to have encouraged a culture of question wars, rather than concentrating on answers. That may well have made sound sense at first, when the site was smaller and there was not yet a set hostility to "personal philosophy" etc..

But is it the best way to make the site (which incidentally is very high up on google) a good one?

Comment: Why would focusing on answers be better? What is the "culture of question wars" that virmaior would have encouraged?

Comment: in answer to your 2nd question, i mean comments on questions which ask for clarification etc. when it's not obvious it is needed. in answer to your 1st question, because it would be a lot easier to enforce

Comment: I don't think so. Generally, good questions inspire good answers and it's very difficult to encourage good answers on mediocre questions. These clarifications are often needed because otherwise answerers are left in the dark as to what the OP actually needs to know.

Comment: oh and i think that questions are generally better than answers, at present. not to get 'philosophical' but "philosophical" questions don't even need to be that clear, isn't that what answers are for??

Comment: This is still an SE site and we need well-formed questions to make this work. This site is to help people study philosophy, not to "do philosophy themselves" - which is, admittedly, a very broad and imprecise statement. Anyway, see the [tour] and [ask] for why good questions are important.

Comment: i think so. ofc good questions will get better answers, but i really believe that people mostly vote on questions for somewhat crazy reasons, like *you made me want to know the answer*. i have no idea what gets good votes on answers, tho from my limited experience it strikes me as just as random

Comment: not sure what you mean by "do philosophy themselves" or what relevance it has to my question or comments.

Comment: hm, i think i get you? you're saying that **questions have to be clear because answers can't do philosophy**. right? that may be super helpful (and thanks for your patience)

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. While some philosophical questions may seem vague, that is not the kind of question we intend to answer here. We can discuss positions on those questions, as that perspective helps with asking well-formed questions.

Comment: is that right? i mean you don't have to couch that in imprecision, it does make good sense: if you want good answers ask easily answered questions. or whatever. anyway, i stand by my original claim.